# Do there exists infinitely many primes that satisfy $p_a-p_b=k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I have read that Terence Tao proved that there exists infinitely many primes that satisfy $p_n-p_{n-1}\le246$ ($p_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ prime)
I want to know whether it has been proven that there exists infinitely many primes that satisfy $p_a-p_{b}=k$, where $k$ is an integer ($k$ can be greater than 246)? I am specifically asking for equality (in the case of $p_n-p_{n-1}\le246$ there is only an inequality ). I am asking for a specific value of $k$.

**Edit-1** The two primes need not be consecutive.
**Edit-2**
Suppose $p_a-p_{b}=k$ is true only for finite number of primes.
This would mean that there does not exists infinitely many primes that satisfy $p_n-p_{n-1}\le246$ (because it is not true for $k=1,2,....246$) leading to a contradiction.
This means that there exists infinitely many primes that satisfy $p_n-p_{n-1}= k~$ for some $k\le246$ even though we don't know the exact value of $k$ for which it is true .
Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: If you only want _existence_ of some such $k\le 246$, of course the result you mentioned implies that. So you mean _for_a_specific_ $k$!? Might be good to emphasize that.

Comment: @Asher2211 Your Edit-2 is correct, i.e., there's at least one even $2 \le k \le 246$ for which there are an infinite number of primes that satisfy $p_n - p_{n-1} = k$, but we don't know how many and which one(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a special case of [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture) which states

> ... for a finite set of linear forms $a_1 + b_1 n, a_2 + b_2 n, \ldots, a_k + b_k n$ with $b_i \ge 1$, there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ for which they are all prime, unless there is a congruence condition preventing this ...

There are $2$ linear forms involved in your question, with them being $a_1 = 0$ and $b_1 = 1$, i.e., $n$, plus $a_2 = k$ and $b_2 = 1$, i.e., $k + n$. Therefore, $n = p_b$ and $k + n = p_a$ gives what you're asking about, i.e.,

$$p_a - p_b = k \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

I'm quite certain no specific examples of Dickson's conjecture, like what you're asking about, have yet been proven.

Comment: how is dirchlet theorem not valid here?

Comment: @vidyarthi 'Primes in arithmetic progression' only gives that for any given $k$ you can find some $n$ such that there are two primes differing by $nk$; there's no way of mandating $n=1$.

Comment: @vidyarthi We know there are infinitely many primes in the sequence $7x+4$, for example, but that doesn't tell us there are infinitely many primes that differ by $4$; or by $8$; or by $16$; etc.

Comment: @vidyarthi Dirichlet’s theorem is quite irrelevant here.  You could use it to show that $p_a - p_b$ is frequently divisible by $k$, but this can be deduced from just having infinitely many primes (i.e. Euclid).

Comment: @vidyarthi I have nothing to add to the comments from Steven, Arturo and Erick about how Dirichlet's theorem doesn't apply here.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I have made another edit. Can you check if that is correct?